# If $20 $ random numbers are selected independently from the interval $(0,1) $ probability that the sum of these numbers is at least $8$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, uniform-distribution, sum

> If $20 $ random numbers are selected independently from the interval
> $(0,1) $  what is the probability that the sum of these numbers is
> at least $8$?

I tried to take this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285362/choosing-two-random-numbers-in-0-1-what-is-the-probability-that-sum-of-them   as reference  but the step where there is a double integral, I got stuck, do I have to make 20 integrals?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

Comment: In addition to Łukasz's comment: A normal approximation works well here.

Comment: Use the methods applied to a closely related problem at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194352.  A direct method is to compute the entire distribution of the sum of those $20$ random values; many ways to perform that calculation are presented at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41467.

Comment: While it's perfectly possible to do the calculation, if you're doing an exercise, I expect the intent is probably that you'd use a normal approximation; you're not far into the tail, it should do quite well. Of course, more revealing still would be to do both.

Comment: Please suggest edits or policy violation if any , before requesting to close the question

Comment: People have kindly suggested several possible approaches but you have not said why they do not help you so it is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: @mdewey actually I haven't tried those suggestions  yet , I will do and inform the progress as soon  as possible  .

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: @mdewey please have a look and comment , I used clt concept here , In the answer

Comment: In addition to the Irwin-Hall distribution and normal approximation, I'll add as a third option that you can estimate this quantity with Monte Carlo methods.

Comment: Your edited version of the question is thoroughly answered in the thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41467 (mentioned in my first comment).

Comment: For reference, an exact (rational) answer can be obtained from [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+%288%5E20+-20*7%5E20+%2B20*19*6%5E20+%2F+2+-20*19*18*5%5E20+%2F+6+%2B20*19*18*17*4%5E20+%2F+24+-20*19*18*17*16*3%5E20+%2F+5%21+%2B20*19*18*17*16*15*2%5E20+%2F+6%21+-20*19*18*17*16*15*14%2F7%21%29+%2F+20%21) as `285575185325803781/304112751022080000`, equal to `0.9390437736202311` in double-precision floating point. (A black-box calculation can be had with `1 - CDF(UniformSumDistribution(20), 8)`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be helpful to have a "gross reality check" (or grc) ((some people call it a [sanity check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check))) that comes at the problem side-ways and can tell you if you are doing something wrong.

Here is R-code to simulate the problem, and give an estimate:

```r
set.seed(1)
  temp <- numeric(length=20000)
  for(i in 1:20000){
    # y <- sample(c(0,1),20,T)   # (wrong! Thanks @whuber) discrete
    y <- runif(n=20)  # continuous outputs
    
    # is it 8 or more
    temp[i] <- ifelse(sum(y) >= 8, 1, 0)
  }
  mean(temp)
```

This is what it gives:

```r
> mean(temp)
[1] 0.94265
```

After 20k trials I would expect the estimate to be within 1% or 0.1% of theoretical result.

Here is a plot of 20 runs, showing convergence and spread of the estimate

[image]

Here is the list of the tail value for the runs, and the residual from the ensemble mean:

```r
          mean      err
    1  0.94265  0.00324
    2  0.94160  0.00219
    3  0.93955  0.00014
    4  0.94190  0.00249
    5  0.93775 -0.00166
    6  0.93580 -0.00361
    7  0.93840 -0.00101
    8  0.93500 -0.00441
    9  0.93735 -0.00206
    10 0.94030  0.00089
    11 0.94160  0.00219
    12 0.93965  0.00024
    13 0.94005  0.00064
    14 0.93810 -0.00131
    15 0.93990  0.00049
    16 0.93995  0.00054
    17 0.93735 -0.00206
    18 0.94125  0.00184
    19 0.94070  0.00129
    20 0.93935 -0.00006
```

They don't move around much.  The standard deviation in those means is ~0.00204, while the ensemble mean is 93.941%

The estimates 93.94% (analytic) and 93.941% (simulated) are ~0.0048 standard deviations apart, which indicates to me that the analytic approach is on the right track.

Comment: **This answer is incorrect,** because it samples from the set $\{0,1\}$ rather than the entire interval $(0,1).$  Contrast it with `n <- 1e6; mean(colSums(matrix(runif(20*n), 20)) >= 8)`.

Comment: What is a "gross reality check"? Is that distinct from a [sanity check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check)?

Comment: @whuber - I always learn from you!  My answer has been updated.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Galen - One of the people who taught me the most (Walt Flom) referred to them as gross reality checks.  That term sticks with me.  Sanity check is a suitable synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ \ X_i $ be the $ \ i^{th}$ number selected where $\ i= 1,2,3,4...20 $

$To $ $ calculate $

$ \ P( \sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i \ge 8 )  $

$ E(\ X_i) = \frac{(0+1)}{2} $      $ [uniform $  $ distribution ] $

$ E(\ X_i) = \frac{1}{2} $

$ E(\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i) = 20/2 = 10 $

$ Var(\ X_i) = \frac{\ (1-0)^2}{12} $      $ [uniform $  $ distribution ] $

$ Var(\ X_i) = \frac{\ 1}{12} $

$ Var(\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i) = 20/12 = 5/3  $

$ \ P(\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i  - E(\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i)  }{\sqrt Var(\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i)}   \ge \frac {8 -E(\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i)}{\sqrt Var(\sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i}  )  $

$ \ P(\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{20} X_i  - 10)  }{\sqrt {5/3}}   \ge \frac {8 -10}{\sqrt 5/3}  )  $

$
1- P(Z \le -1.55)$

= $ 0.9394 $ $ approx $

Comment: The inequality sign in the second-to-last line should be flipped, I think.

Comment: @coolserdash why , I calculated the right hand side its -1.55 so why would the inequality sign change ??

Comment: The standard normal CDF $\Phi(x)$ gives $P(X\leq x)$. So $1-\Phi(x)$ gives $P(X>x)$ which is what you want and calculated. Accordingly, the notation should read $1 - P(Z\leq -1.55)$ which is $P(Z>-1.55)$ (the equality doesn't matter here because it's a continuous variable).

Comment: @coolserdash oh yes thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a histogram of 100,000 simulations each taking the sum of 20 uniform random deviates.  Based on this simulation the sum of uniform deviates is well approximated by a normal distribution with an estimated mean of 10.004 and an estimated variance of 1.680.  Using the normal approximation the probability that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge 8$ is $0.94$.

[image]

Code follows:

```
data uniform;
  do sim=1 to 100000;
    do i=1 to 20;
        y=rand('uniform');
        output;
    end;
end;
run;

proc means data=uniform noprint;
by sim;
var y;
output out=out sum(y)=sum;
run;


ods graphics / height=3in width=6in border=no;

proc sgplot data=out;
histogram sum;
density sum / type=normal;
run;

proc means data=out mean var;
var sum;
output out=estimates mean(sum)=mean var(sum)=var;
run;

data estimates;
set estimates;
prob=1-cdf('normal',8,mean,sqrt(var));
run;

proc print data=estimates noobs;
var prob;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks [@EngrStudent](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/22452/engrstudent)!  Does simply adding the phrase "Code follows:" produce the code formatting?

Comment: No it doesn't. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for details.