# Combinatorial/probabilistic meaning/analogy for $x^n / n!$

Tags: probability, interpretation, combinatorics, taylor-series

The expression $x^n / n!$ appears in the infinite sum defining $e^x$ and similar terms in the sums defining $\cos(x)$, $\sin(x)$, etc.
I would like to know if there is some combinatorial/probabilistic meaning or analogy to the term $x^n / n!$  and appropriately an example of a scenario of selection or decision making that could be represented by a consecutive sum of these terms similar to the infinite sums defining $e^x$ or $\cos(x)/\sin(x)$.

In other words: some probabalistic/combinatorical scenario whose calculation would converge to one of these functions ($e^x/\cos(x)/\sin(x)$).

Comment: There are extremely many.  One of the best known is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: @whuber I do not understand what $x^n/n!$ has to do with derangements, can you clarify?

Answer (score 6):

If you divide every term by $e^{x}$ so the sum is $1$

then you get the Poisson distribution probability $e^{-x} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$

of seeing $n$ items when the expected number of items  is $x$.

Comment: this @Henry still has the term e^−x
. could you give some intuitive example of a set of calculations that converge to e^x?

Answer (score 6):

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ random variables, then (check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683574/321264) for details)

$$P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le x\right)=\frac{x^n}{n!}\quad,\, x\in [0,1]$$

In other words, $x^n/n!$ is the volume of the region $$\left\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n: x_1,\ldots,x_n\ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \le x\right\}$$ whenever $x\in [0,1]$. When $x=1$, this is related to the volume of a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#The_standard_simplex).

We can also define a stopping rule associated with the $X_i$'s as

$$N=\min\left\{n: \sum_{i=1}^n X_i>x\right\} \quad,\, x\in [0,1]$$

Then, using the result above,

$$E(N)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(N>n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le x\right)=e^x$$

This is in fact a popular exercise discussed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/194352/119261) previously.

Comment: What I like about this is the result is simple and yet the interpretation cannot be more manifesting. +1.

Comment: @StubbornAtom what is the meaning of E(N)?