# Estimate the Euler–Mascheroni constant ($\gamma$) by Monte Carlo simulations

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, algorithms, numerical-integration

The Euler–Mascheroni constant is defined simply as the limiting difference between harmonic series and the natural logarithm.
$$\gamma =\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum _{k=1}^{n}{\frac {1}{k}}-\ln n\right)$$

I was interested in the estimations of Mathematical constants using Monte Carlo simulations after seeing the following post
[Approximate $e$ using Monte Carlo Simulation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193990/approximate-e-using-monte-carlo-simulation) and reading about the countless experiments to approximate $\pi$ (Buffon's needle/noodle etc.). I want to showcase a few nice examples of MC simulations in calculating mathematical constants to help motivate the idea.

My question is,
**How can you design a non-trival MC simulation to estimate $\gamma$ ?** (I say non-trivial since I could just integrate $\ln n$ for a sufficiently large $n$ using numeric MC integration, but this doesn't seem to be a very interesting showcase.)

I thought it might be possible to do using the [Gumbel Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution) with $\mu=0, \beta=1$ (since mean of the Gumbel Distribution is  $E(X)=\mu+\beta\gamma$). <s>However, I'm not sure how to implement this.</s>

**Edit:** Thanks to Xi'an and S. Catterall for pointing out that the instructions for simulating the Gumbel Dist were on the Wikipedia article itself.
$${\displaystyle Q(p)=\mu -\beta \ln(-\ln(p)),}$$ where you draw $p$ from $(0,1)$.

Simple Mathematica code for $10^6$ draws,

```
gumbelrand = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^6, 1}];
Mean[-Log[-Log[gumbelrand]]]
```

Comment: Since the Gumbel distribution is straightforward to simulate (eg by inverse cdf), approximating the expectation by Monte Carlo is also immediate.

Comment: In fact there are explicit instructions for simulating from the Gumbel distribution on the wikipedia page you linked to.

Comment: Oh yes you're right. I didn't spot that. Editing it onto the post but I'll leave it open for some time incase there are some other answers.

Comment: If $U$ is a sample of random numbers uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$ then, as you have found,  $\frac1n \sum -\log(-\log(u_i))$ is a simulated value of $\gamma$.  But there are others which are usually better and not much more complicated, such as  $\frac1n \sum \left(\frac1{u_i}+\frac{1}{\log(1-u_i)}\right)$ which is in a sense typically about $18.2$ or $18.7$ times closer

Comment: Hi Henry, I just tried that relation instead and it does indeed work much better. Can you link me to some reference for it? I couldn't figure out how it arises.

Comment: @BhorisDhanjal See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980593/some-integral-representations-of-the-euler-mascheroni-constant for how Henry's suggestion arises

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to use the exponential and logarithmic functions for your method, you can estimate the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals)  using importance sampling from exponential random variables.  Letting $X \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ we can write the Euler–Mascheroni constant as:

$$\begin{align}
\gamma 
&= - \int \limits_0^\infty e^{-x} \log x \ dx \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^\infty (-\log x) \cdot p_X(x) \ dx \\[12pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(- \log X). \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

Consequently, we can take $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID Exp}(1)$ and use the estimator:

$$\hat{\gamma}_n
\equiv - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i.$$

The law of large numbers ensures that this is a strongly consistent estimator for $\gamma$, so it will converge stochastically to this value as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  We can implement this in `R` quite simply as follows.  Using $n=10^6$ simulations we get quite close to the true value.

```
#Create function to estimate Euler–Mascheroni constant
simulate.EM <- function(n) { -mean(log(rexp(n, rate = 1))) }

#Perform simulations
set.seed(1)
simulate.EM(10^6)
[1] 0.5772535

#True value is 0.5772157
#Our simulation is correct to four DP
```

Comment: +1. (1) Notice that $\log X$ has a [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution). (2) Therefore you can efficiently generate the $x_i$ with a standard, universal random number generator that returns a U$(0,1)$ variable: `mean(-log(-log(runif(1e6))))` (in `R`).

Comment: Yes, that is a good point.  I figured that since I am already using the logarithm function, I could reasonably go directly to the exponential distribution.

Answer (score 7):

The following facts yields an extremely simple method.

If $U \sim U(0,1)$ and $W = 1 - \{1/U\}$ with $\{x\}$ denoting the
fractional part of $x$, we have $E(W) = \gamma$ and variance $Var(W)=
\psi(2)+2\int_0^1\ln\Gamma(t+1)\,dt -(1-\gamma)^2 \approx 0.081915$ where $\psi(x)$ is
the [digamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)
function.

So add up enough $W$'s.

Comment: This is interesting.  Do you know a reference for this fact?

Comment: No, my notes show I derived it 2002 while simulating some Markov chains.

Comment: I have added an additional answer proving the validity of this method.

Comment: This is the best answer as it doesn’t anything but uniform numbers

Answer (score 6):

Luis Mendo (2020) presented an algorithm that returns 1 with probability equal to $\gamma$, using the series expansion found by Sondow (2010), when the algorithm is given an infinite stream of fair coin flips, rather than a stream of uniform random variables in (0, 1). I have described it in my [page on Bernoulli factory algorithms](https://peteroupc.github.io/bernoulli.html#Euler_ndash_Mascheroni_constant___gamma), which also includes algorithms to sample probabilities for many other kinds of functions and constants.

REFERENCES:

- Mendo, L., "[Simulating a coin with irrational bias using rational arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.14901.pdf)", arXiv:2010.14901 [math.PR], 2020.
- Sondow, Jonathan, “New Vacca-Type Rational Series for Euler's Constant and Its 'Alternating' Analog ln 4/π.”. In *Additive Number Theory: Festschrift in honor of the sixtieth birthday of Melvyn B. Nathanson*, 331 (2010).

Answer (score 6):

*Here I will expand on the method described by [Balasubramanian Narasimhan](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/244893/) in his answer.*

It is possible to simulate the Euler-Mascheroni constant by elementary methods, using uniform random variables and elementary functions.  This is less efficient than the other method I have shown in my other answer, which uses the exponential and logarithmic functions.  However, it has the advantage of requiring only uniform pseudo-random numbers and elementary mathematical operations.

Let $U \sim \text{U}(0,1)$ and define $X = 1 - \{ 1/U \}$, where the latter denotes the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of a number.  We can use the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) and change-of-variable $r = 1/u$ to obtain the expectation:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) 
&= \mathbb{E}(1 - \{ 1/U \}) \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^1 (1 - \{ 1/u \}) \ du \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1 - \{ r \}}{r^2} \ dr \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1 - r + \lfloor r \rfloor}{r^2} \ dr \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_1^\infty \Big( \frac{\lceil r \rceil}{r^2} -\frac{1}{r} \Big) \ dr \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_1^\infty \Big( \frac{1}{\lfloor r \rfloor} -\frac{1}{r} \Big) \ dr \\[6pt]
&= \gamma. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

(For the penultimate step, see a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223474/).)  Since $\mathbb{E}(X) = \gamma$ (and it can also be shown that the variance is finite), taking $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID U}(0,1)$ yields the natural estimator:

$$\hat{\gamma}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = 1 - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \{ 1/U_i \}.$$

The law of large numbers ensures that this is a strongly consistent estimator for $\gamma$, so it will converge stochastically to this value as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  We can implement this in `R` quite simply as follows. Using $n=10^6$ simulations we get reasonably close to the true value (though not as close as with the estimator in my other answer).

```
#Create function to estimate Euler–Mascheroni constant
simulate.EM <- function(n) { 
  U  <- runif(n)
  UU <- 1/U
  Y  <- 1-UU+floor(UU)
  mean(Y) }

#Perform simulations
set.seed(1)
simulate.EM(10^6)
[1] 0.576843

#True value is 0.5772157
#Our simulation is correct to three DP
```

Comment: +1 Using `microbenchmark` on `simulate.EM <- function(n = 1e+5) {UU <- 1/runif(n); mean(1-UU+floor(UU))}` and `gumbel <- function(n = 1e+5) mean(-log(-log(runif(n))))`, this method actually appear to be about 8% faster than the one based on the Gumbel distribution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a horrible but fun way, think of the [Coupon collector's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) problem.

Suppose that you have $n$ different cards which you want to collect. At each time $t\,\in\,\mathbb{N}$, you buy a card, which has probability $1/n$ of being the i-th card (even if you already have it) until you have all cards. You are not allowed to trade with other players. The question is: on average, how long does it take for you to collect all cards?

Being more precise, let $(C_t)_{t=1}^\infty$ an i.i.d. sequence of cards, $C_1 \, \sim \, U(\{1,\ldots,n\})$, and consider $S_t = \{C_1, \ldots, C_t\}$, the set of unique cards that you have at time $t$. Defining

$$\tau = \inf\{t\,\in\,\mathbb{N}: |S_t| = n\},$$

your goal is to compute $E[\tau]$. You can show that (just check wikipedia if you are bored)

$$E[\tau] = n\sum_{t=1}^n\frac{1}{t}\quad. $$

Therefore, you have that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{E[\tau]}{n} - \log(n)\right) = \gamma \quad.$$

Make $n$ large and use Monte Carlo to estimate $E[\tau]$. Or produce a card game with those rules, dare your friends to collect all cards, and do a real life Monte Carlo.